# Source Rule publish error for custom rule created on Custom Item Type

Tags: drools, sap-commerce-cloud, rule-engine

Hi Created new Rule condition and trying to publish it, during publish getting exception mismatched input 'in' in query.

Rule Impex Created to support condition:

```
# Rule Definition Category
$lang=en
INSERT_UPDATE RuleConditionDefinitionCategory ; id[unique=true]    ; name[lang=$lang]   ; priority 
                                              ; product_visibility ; Product visibility ; 1300     
                                              
                                              
INSERT_UPDATE RuleConditionDefinition ; id[unique = true]                ; priority ; allowsChildren ; translatorId                            ; translatorParameters ; categories(id)     
                                      ; block_resource            ; 200      ; false          ; resourceBlockConditionTranslator  ;                      ; product_visibility 
UPDATE RuleConditionDefinition ; id[unique = true]                ; name[lang = $lang] ; breadcrumb[lang = $lang]             
                               ; block_resource            ; Resource Block     ; Resource Block is  {block_resource}  
INSERT_UPDATE RuleConditionDefinitionParameter ; definition(id)[unique = true]    ; id[unique = true] ; priority ; type                                                                      ; value ; required[default = true] ; validators                       
                                               ; block_resource            ; block_resource    ; 1100     ; List(ItemType(ResourceBlock))                                             ;       ; false                    ;                                  
                                               
INSERT_UPDATE RuleConditionDefinitionRuleTypeMapping ; definition(id)[unique = true]    ; ruleType(code)[default = CustomSourceRule][unique = true] 
                                                     ; block_resource
```

Rule Translator Class will translate the rule during publish and converted into drl:

```
@Override
    public RuleIrCondition translate(RuleCompilerContext context, RuleConditionData conditionData,
            RuleConditionDefinitionData definition) throws RuleCompilerException
    {
        if (!checkParameters(conditionData.getParameters(), definition.getParameters()))
        {
            return new RuleIrFalseCondition();
        }

        return condition(context, conditionData);
    }

    private RuleIrCondition condition(RuleCompilerContext context, RuleConditionData conditionData)
    {
        List<String> resourceBlockCodes = getParamValue(conditionData, GerdauCoreDroolsConstants.Condition.ResourceBlock.Parameter.VALUE);
        return createCondition(productVariable(context), GERDAU_RESOURCE_BLOCK, RuleIrAttributeOperator.IN, resourceBlockCodes);
    }
```

Stack trace:

```
ERROR [RulePublisher-Thread-59] [DefaultRulePublishingSpliterator] ERROR Parser returned a null Package de/hybris/platform/droolsruleenginetrigger_test_product_visibility_message_test_oneRuleMedia.drl
ERROR [RuleEngine-module-swapping-0] [DefaultRuleEngineKieModuleSwapper] DroolsInitializationException occurred {}
de.hybris.platform.ruleengine.exception.DroolsInitializationException: Initialization of rule engine failed during the deployment phase: [ERR 102] Line 12:41 mismatched input 'in' in query, [ERR 102] Line 24:45 mismatched input 'in' in rule "a8a6f084-9d97-4681-a9fd-bce784f25fcc", Parser returned a null Package
        at de.hybris.platform.ruleengine.init.impl.DefaultRuleEngineKieModuleSwapper.deployRules(DefaultRuleEngineKieModuleSwapper.java:803) ~[ruleengineserver.jar:?]
        at de.hybris.platform.ruleengine.init.impl.DefaultRuleEngineKieModuleSwapper.lambda$18(DefaultRuleEngineKieModuleSwapper.java:365) ~[ruleengineserver.jar:?]
        at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$7$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:271) ~[?:?]
        at java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListSpliterator.forEachRemaining(ArrayList.java:1655) ~[?:?]
        at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:484) ~[?:?]
        at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:474) ~[?:?]
        at java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(ReduceOps.java:913) ~[?:?]
        at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234) ~[?:?]
        at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect(ReferencePipeline.java:578) ~[?:?]
        at de.hybris.platform.ruleengine
```

Comment: Please provide the rule itself. We can't help you figure out what you did wrong if you don't show us what you did. :)

Comment: Hi @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas,I have updated the details

Comment: could you provide the DRL itself?

Comment: @EstebanAliverti drl is getting generated after successful publish of rule

Comment: I am able to resolve the issue as there was an issue with field mapping in Custom Translator